# SafeCracker Registration - unknown error

Tags: members, safecracker, safecracker-registration

I'm using SafeCracker Registration. Right now, I have a form with 4 fields:

- title
- email
- password
- password_confirm

When the form displays, I click submit without entering any data in the form. I get this on the next page:

```
The following errors were encountered

You have just been sent an email containing membership activation instructions.
```

No email is received. No member is registered. My opening tag is this:

```
{exp:safecracker channel="profiles" class="form-horizontal" datepicker="no" error_handling="inline" include_jquery="no" register_member="yes" return="registration/form" safecracker_head="no"}
```

NOTE: "profiles" is a valid Channel. It contains a number of fields, but I haven't started trying to populate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. Safecracker Registration v1.2 is finished and waiting for a release. I just haven't had time to document the changes, and update the documentation, but it makes a lot of usability improvements like the one you mentioned.

Email support[at]objectivehtml.com and I will be happy to get your setup with the latest version.